# Modify Meteor-React ToDo List Example to Display List Items Created Within a Time Range

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-react

I'm working through the Meteor-React Todo list tutorial as found here https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app

As per [8.4](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react/commit/f48c03507b9438ad4c1e9a48a2d5b82b1bd354ea), we can add a button that hides todo items that are checked off. We do this by querying the DB for items that checked equals true.

```
if (this.state.hideCompleted) {
        // If hide completed is checked, filter tasks
        query = {checked: {$ne: true}};
    }
```

If I wanted to only display todo items that were created in the last 30 minutes, ie todo items expire after 30 minutes, what would I set the query to?

My guess is something like this

```
if (this.state.hideExpired) {
        // If hideExpired state true, only display todo items created in the last 30 minutes.
        query = {{$ne: (currentTime - createdAt) < 30 minutes}};
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty close but you need to use `$lte` or `$gte` instead of `$eq`:

```
if (this.state.hideExpired) {
  var now = new Date();
  var thirtyMinutesAgo = new Date() - 30 * 60 * 1000; //
  query = { createdAt: { $gte: thirtyMinutesAgo }}
}
```

Note that this query *will not be reactive.* This is because `thirtyMinutesAgo` is not a reactive variable. If you want items to dynamically disappear from the list as they age you'll need to make time itself reactive. For this I recommend the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package. With that package installed the above code would become:

```
if (this.state.hideExpired) {
  var now = new Date();
  var thirtyMinutesAgo = Chronos.currentTime() - 30 * 60 * 1000; //
  query = { createdAt: { $gte: thirtyMinutesAgo }}
}
```

`Chronos.currentTime()` will update every second by default and `thirtyMinutesAgo` will be a reactive variable.